# Relative, partial route match

Tags: react-router, material-ui

In React Router 6, how can a path be partially matched (relative to its hierarchy) without knowing the complete hierarchy? For example, if a navigation element is in the middle of the hierarchy, how can it match just the relative part of the path?

e.g. with the following routes:

```
/users
/users/1
/users/1/edit
```

Assuming there was a visual user picker which returned (just) the user's id - how could the current id be determined via the route alone?

Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/navtabs-material-demo-forked-bc356?file=/demo.tsx) illustrating the same issue using MUI's Tabs component. The idea would be for the active tab to show as active (as in this [demo](https://mui.com/components/tabs/#main-content))